# How to change permissions in /etc/fstab so that anyone can read and write

Tags: fstab

I am making a custom ubuntu installation by customizing the iso. I need to change permission in /etc/fstab so that anyone can read and write.

I have tried chmod filename but obviously that does not work.

How can i get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is why `/etc/fstab` is read only for users:
*This is because even a small, unnoticed error could cause the system to malfunction, and repair could be difficult for ordinary users. When modifying configuration files such as /etc/fstab, it is important to make an emergency backup copy*
Source: http://www.linfo.org/etc_fstab.html

Its not recommended to give write permission on this file to users
Its not needed for most uses cases

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /etc/fstab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1302 Mar  5 10:24 /etc/fstab

# Not recommended: Give write perms for all
user@host:~$ sudo chmod 666 /etc/fstab
user@host:~$ ls -l /etc/fstab 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1302 Mar  5 10:24 /etc/fstab

# Restore default file perms
user@host:~$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/fstab
```

Comment: chmod does not work.

Comment: I want to change the file permissions in the mounted iso, u know the one in which u add packages to install and make changes to the ui and configuration files. I want to change the /etc/fstab permission there so that when i install the iso on a different hard drive the fstab file will by default be read and write for everyone

Comment: chmod dont work, sudo chmod as writen does - it seems you do not know why you want fstab writeable for all - please vote up the answer

Comment: - He is asking about a custom iso so he is using a chroot making him root user. - still wont work. When installing from the custom ISO /etc/fstab will be 0644.. Doing it at the custom ISO level you can do a %post from a preseed file.